# google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid recognition 'config': Bad language code

Tags: python, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to explore the Google cloud speech to text service: https://github.com/google/making_with_ml/tree/master/ai_dubs

I did all the setup metioned in the git's readme page.

But, While running the command with a sample audio, getting bellow error.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
**(venv) root@Dilli-Latitude-3410:/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs# python dubber.py media/hello-universe.wav "en" outputDirectory --targetLangs '["ta"]'**
Transcribing audio
Uploading to the cloud...
Transcribing...
Diarizing: False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Invalid recognition 'config': Bad language code."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1630218255.079956548","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2404:6800:4002:806::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Invalid recognition 'config': Bad language code.","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dubber.py", line 523, in <module>
    fire.Fire(dub)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 138, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 463, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 672, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "dubber.py", line 443, in dub
    transcripts = get_transcripts_json(os.path.join(
  File "dubber.py", line 110, in get_transcripts_json
    res = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio).result()
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1p1beta1/services/speech/client.py", line 457, in long_running_recognize
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/dilli/mine/hackathon/ai_dubs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
**google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid recognition 'config': Bad language code.**
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the language code you used, as denoted by the error returned:

```
    details = "Invalid recognition 'config': Bad language code."
```

The dubber is basically using the speech-to-text and text-to-speech Google APIs.

I couldn't determine if it's the `"en"` or the `"ta"` that generates the error, but I'm guessing it's the `"ta"` one...

If you check the language code page [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) you can see you'll need to use `"ta-IN"` instead of `"ta"`

Comment: Hi @Edo, Thanks for your response.
I have tried that too, but the error remains same.

====>#python dubber.py media/3.wav "en" outputDirectory --targetLangs '["ta-IN"]'

====>#python dubber.py media/3.wav "en-US" outputDirectory --targetLangs '["ta"]'

====>#python dubber.py media/3.wav "en-US" outputDirectory --targetLangs '["ta-IN"]'